# How can I get Rock Band 1 songs into Rock Band 2?

Tags: rock-band, rock-band-2

As I'm planning to buy Rock Band 3, but I wanted to buy Rock Band 1 & 2 first.

But off course I don't feel like swapping disks all the time and I heard you can actually import games from Rock Band 1 into Rock Band 2, but how do I do this?

Note: I own both a PS3 and a Xbox360, so feel free to answer the question for every platform

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(**Note:** This answer applies to the XBox 360 version. I am not certain whether this is possible on other consoles.)*

Start up Rock Band 1 while connected to XBox Live.  The XBox will tell you there is a title update available; let it patch.

After it patches, there will be an option off the Main Menu to "Export" your songs. Select it and follow the instructions.

Note that this process costs about $5, a few GB of hard drive space, and quite a bit of time... so if you are running low on time, free space, or cash this might not be the option for you.

I can only *assume* that a similar process will work for Rock Band 2 to get the songs into Rock Band 3.

Comment: Note that you can just rent/borrow the disc and it is not necessary to actually own it. You just need a physical copy of RB1. Also, there are three songs on RB1 which are not playable in RB2 due to licensing restrictions. Those are: Run to the Hills by Iron Maiden, Paranoid by Black Sabbath, and Enter Sandman by Metallica. It's currently unknown whether the same import process will be allowed for RB2->RB3.

Comment: Also, the RB1 DLC song "Monsoon" by Tokio Hotel is also unavailable in RB2.

Comment: As of 12/27/2021, this option is no longer available for Xbox 360. It comes up with an error when it takes to the market place that says “this item is no longer available.”

Answer (score 3):

If you own an Xbox 360, use an [export disc](http://www.destructoid.com/rock-band-disc-export-update-is-now-live-kind-of-useless-for-now-update--102442.phtml).

If you own a PS3, use an export key.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one else has mentioned it, if you have a Wii, you cannot export your Rock Band songs into Rock Band 2.  You are stuck swapping discs.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your platform, but you can also export more tracks from Lego/Beetles/Green Day Rock Band as well.

Comment: Actually, you can't export Beatles songs for play in RB1/2. They are considered separate products. [Source](http://www.rockband.com/forums/showthread.php?t=143584) With Lego, you can, but you can't just rent it like with RB1, as each game is sold with a key that you need to use to allow export. The free for that game is $10, rather than $5. I don't own Green Day, so I can't comment on that one.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes: Green Day works like Lego, in that each copy of the game comes with a one-time use key that allows you to purchase an export license for $10.